# Replace a character in a section of a string in Bash

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to replace `-` and `:` with `?` only in the middle(second) section delimited by `___` (3 underscore)

input:

```
aaa___bb-bb:bbb___cc-cc:ccc
d-d___d-ddd:d-d___e-e:e
```

output:

```
aaa___bb?bb?bbb___cc-cc:ccc
d-d___d?ddd?d?d___e-e:e
```

I tried below `sed` command but it only replaces the last occurrence of the `-:` in the middle section

```
echo "aaa___bb-bb:bbb___cc-cc:ccc
d-d___d-ddd:d-d___e-e:e" | sed "s|\(___[^_]*\)[-:]\([^_]*___\)|\1?\2|g"
```

Output:

```
aaa___bb-bb?bbb___cc-cc:ccc
d-d___d-ddd:d?d___e-e:e
```

I'm not restricted to only use `sed`. `awk`, `tr`, etc are fine too.

Comment: Is your input coming from a shell variable? A file? A stream?

Comment: Does that matter?  For my script, it's in a pipe (output of a `grep`).

Comment: It matters a bit -- for my existing answer, instead of `<<<"$in"`, then, you'd want to use `< <(grep ...)`.

Comment: (BTW, I'd argue that folks using external utilities unnecessarily is a big part of why shell scripts have their reputation as slow, ie. from the systemd folks. Sure, bash is a particularly slow shell, but it's still an orders-of-magnitude difference in performance between doing a task internally to the shell and shelling out for it, at least when operating on small amount of data. For a shell that processes large amounts of data efficiently, consider ksh93 -- the real David Korne one, not the clones).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pure native bash, with no external utilities:

```
in='aaa___bb-bb:bbb___cc-cc:ccc
d-d___d-ddd:d-d___e-e:e'

while IFS= read -r line; do
   first=${line%%___*}
   last=${line##*___}
   middle=${line#*___}; middle=${middle%___*}
   printf '%s\n' "${first}___${middle//[-:]/?}___${last}"
done <<<"$in"
```

Comment: A better optimization still would perhaps be to replace the `grep` which the OP says the input comes from with a tool which does both the pattern matching and the substitutions in the same process. My bet is on Awk.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
awk -F"___" '{gsub(/[-:]/,"?",$2)}1' OFS="___"
```

Comment: I like this one-liner, however, looking at the performance, @Charles solution is consistently took half the time (28ms vs 11ms) to accomplish the task.

Comment: @Sungam, ...incidentally, awk will be much faster with large enough input files (processing lots of lines); it's the constant startup time that hurts it here.

Comment: (However, with only two lines of input, I'd actually expect a much larger difference than 2x; it'd be interesting to look at the test harness used for collecting those numbers and figure out where its time is being spent).

Answer (score 1):

You were close with sed solution

```
sed -r ':a; s/(___.*)[-:](.*___)/\1?\2/; ta' file
```

conditional branching is what you needed only